# keyup function for multipe input fields in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok i have keyup for multiple input fileds, my problem is because i have two calls, and i want only one. So when code is inserted only one action happens.

```
$(":input").keyup(function() {
    if(is_draft_started == 0) {
        s2 = setInterval('draft("' + frm_name + '")', auto_save_time);
        is_draft_started = 1;
    }
});
```

but with this selector when key is pressed, my function draft is called twice because i have two input fields, is there any solution, to works this only once, so when i press button one, one call exists?

Comment: Don't you have a way to identify the specific input field you want to match? Something like an `id`, a `name` or a `class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter that you have two input fields, only one of these will trigger an event. So I guess that you have some other problems, e.g. attaching the same handler for the field twice. E.g.:

HTML:

```
First input: <input type="text"></input><br/>
Second input: <input type="text"></input><br/>
Total number of calls: <span id="function_calls">0</span>
```

JS:

```
var funcCalls = 0;
$(":input").keyup(function() {
    $('#function_calls').text(++funcCalls);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkennkon/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ID or Classes to specify which input should trigger your function. Example:

```
<input type="text" class="trigger"></input>
<input type="text" class="no_trigger"></input>
<input type="text" class="trigger"></input>
```

Function will be applyied to all inputs with *trigger* class

```
$('input.trigger').keyup(function(){
    alert("called just once");
});
```

check out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/76r7hvos/1/)